# simple python beginner chatgpt bot program bombs on compatibility issues, cannot find workaround

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to learn both Python and simple ChatGPT api programming. The code I came up with was suggested by gpt itself, and in researching the problem I'm having, every code example I can find on the web is basically doing the same thing as the code I'm trying (below).

I started with a "pip3 install openai" and have no errors from that. It's when I run what should be the simplest code I've ever seen that the errors occur.

The errors I'm receiving are essentially telling me that "openai.ChatCompletion.create" is deprecated, so I've tried the recommended alternative call, which is just "openai.Completion.create". That fails too. Both calls are deprecated according to the runtime warnings. Unfortunately, every piece of sample code I can find on Google uses one of these two methods.

I was given two suggestions by the runtime. One was run "openai migrate" which does nothing but give me some strange permissions error on my PICTURES folder of all things.

The more sensible suggestion was digging into the recommended openai api spec and it suggested using "openai.chat.completions.create". When I try that, I get a different error, this time suggesting I've sent too many requests to the API. This is UTTER NONSENSE -- I've made one and exactly one only call to the api to get the error message.

This should not be this hard. I'm running out of options. I've tried every suggested sample I can find; none work; the call I find in the latest api spec (unless I'm misinterpreting) also does not work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import openai

def chat_with_gpt(api_key):
    openai.api_key = api_key

    # Starting a new chat session
    session = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",  # or another model of your choice
        messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}]
    )

    while True:
        prompt = input("Prompt: ")
        if prompt == "/quit":
            break

        try:
            response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                session_id=session["id"],  # Using the same session for continuity
                messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
            )
            print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_key = "mykey"  # I replace with my actual key
    chat_with_gpt(api_key)
```

Comment: The error from your code points you at https://github.com/openai/openai-python, which has an example showing exactly what you need to do. Unclear why you tried all those other things.

Comment: The quota error seems like a different problem; I see the same thing. A simple test would be to upgrade to the minimal paid tier and seeing if that resolves your problem.

Comment: Update: I spent $5 to fund my api account and the sample code on github worked without any errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help @larsks.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding: I already pay $20/month for a GPT-4 subscription and generated my api key while logged into the account from which I have this subscription. So I would have assumed I am already at a minimal paid tier. Are you saying I must pay separately for an api account?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was just pointing out that (a) the github repository seems to have appropriate examples, (b) with a free account I encountered the same rate limit error that you were reporting, and (c) that after upgrading to the paid tier I was able to use the example code successfully. That is the extent of my knowledge on this topic.

Comment: You could use [chatgptpy](https://pypi.org/project/chatgptpy/) instead. You have to define the api key in the environmental variables still, but it does have many features (like saving conversations to a file).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the 'free tier' with OpenAI and use my assisant program multiple times daily, but have never seen a 429 error before. I realize that's not helping you figure out why you were|are getting them. I agree with @larsks that the Github OpenAI repo has good working code examples. Here is my assistant program that works well for my needs. I got much of the code from the OpenAI repo. Replace `<botname>` with a name for your assistant, if you like. :-)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# OpenAI ChatGPT 3.5 chat client

import os
import sys
import openai
from openai import OpenAI


intro = "You are '<botname>' my helpful personal assitant. Where possible, answer the following query with citations from a reference text."

try:
    client = OpenAI(api_key=os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__cause__)
    sys.exit(1)


print('How can I help you <your name>?\n')
while True:
    query = input("> ")
    if query == "Done":
        print('Bye! -<botname>')
        break

    try:
        chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
                messages=[{"role": "user", "content": intro+'query:"""'+query+'"""',}],
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            temperature=0.2,
            top_p=1,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0
        )

    except openai.APIConnectionError as e:
        print("The server could not be reached")
        print(e.__cause__)  # an underlying Exception, likely raised within httpx.

    except openai.RateLimitError as e:
        print("A 429 status code was received; we should back off a bit.")

    except openai.APIStatusError as e:
        print("Another non-200-range status code was received")
        print(e.status_code)
        print(e.response)

    # Print out our results
    print('<botname>:')
    print('',chat_completion.choices[0].message.content, '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the excellent code sample J. What I ultimately found is that for my code to work, I DID have to drop $5 and buy a batch of api credits. Apparently just having the ChatGPT 4 paid membership doesn't grant you the right to make calls to the API--even though the API key generation page will happily generate keys for you all day. To a beginner, it would seem that I had all the pieces in place. Sadly, no.

Comment: Hi @markaaronky. Glad you were able to get that sorted, and your welcome, I'm always happy to share code! :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this one is that my code was indeed correct, but it was necessary to make a separate purchase of tokens from OpenAI... my paid ChatGPT membership was not enough.

It was my misunderstanding that by just having an OpenAI account through which I was paying for GPT-4, and had access to the token generation page through my account--which would happily generate a key for me--that I had already paid for everything necessary to make this work.

An extra $5 later for a batch of tokens and the code works as it was intended,